# Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET 5 and Identity vs custom user database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got an existing ASP.NET 4 project consisting of a web api and a Single-page-application which is consuming the api. I've done the jwt implementation like described here http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ , however to my big disappointment this is not so easy to port over to ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6.. I need to be able to have my own SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class (or equivalent), since I'm authorizing my users against a local database of mine.

Inside the SimpleauthorizationServerProvider I'm:

1. looking up the context's username and password in my local users db, returns an error or continues
2. creating a var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
3. adding claims - eg. identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));, also setting roles like eg. identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
4. finally, context.Validated(identity);

So I can use [Authorize] or even claims to protect my web api routes.

I've done a lot of googling on this, but I can't seem to find enough info on how to achieve this. As the author of the article linked to above says:

*"The authentication/authorization in ASP,NET 5 is really different than this version, until now you can not issue access token, you can just consume them, You need to relay on identity provider for this task. So there is no direct way to upgrade this project to the latest ASP.NET 5 without using external identity provider."*

I guess what I'm hoping for is help to figure out how to port that example over to ASP.NET 5, the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict) - I think gives you what you need.

This is practically all the configuration I needed:

**ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddOpenIddictCore<Application>(config => config.UseEntityFramework()); //added this line
```

**Configure**

```
app.UseOpenIddictCore(builder =>
{
    // tell openiddict you're wanting to use jwt tokens
    builder.Options.UseJwtTokens();
    // NOTE: for dev consumption only! for live, this is not encouraged!
    builder.Options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
    builder.Options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
});

// use jwt bearer authentication
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    // these urls must match the value in the payload posted from the client side during login
    options.Audience = "http://localhost:58292/";
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:58292/";
});
```

There are one or two other minor things, such as your DbContext needs to derive from `OpenIddictContext<ApplicationUser, Application, ApplicationRole, string>`.

You can see a full length explanation (including links to the github repo) on this blog post:
http://capesean.co.za/blog/asp-net-5-jwt-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

There is a jwt bearer example here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample

Comment: When I tried to run it I got "Method 'get_Configuration' in type 'WrappedApplicationEnvironment' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation." - Also, I couldn't see where in the code I'd add additional claims to the identity?

Comment: Might you still be using rc1 instead of rc2?

Comment: This example should be aligned with v1.0.0-rc2-16216. So it may not work anymore on rc1-update1. You may get nightly builds from https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext.

Comment: I'd try out nightly if the example you linked to did have everything I'm looking for. However as I mentioned before, I can't see where I'd add additional claims to the identity. Also where would the logic go to authenticate the user from username/password input sent in json to a /token endpoint, database lookups etc? The closest thing i've yet seen is https://github.com/mrsheepuk/ASPNETSelfCreatedTokenAuthExample and thats definitely not production ready yet

Comment: Humm. Maybe this repo can shed some light. https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNet5TemplateCookieAuthentication/blob/master/src/Authentication/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L25-L33

Comment: It is very interesting at least, although I'm using jwt and storing the claims them inside the token instead of a cookie. This however should probably help me get a little closer, so thanks!